# Customizing a L450 laptop: Isn't DIMM2 faster than SODIMM because of dual channel ? (screenshot)

Tags: memory, lenovo-laptop, dual-channel

[image: http://i.imgur.com/D8KA5y3.jpg]

here is the US versions:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/aJfjDE6.jpg]

SODIMM are smaller sticks, but this laptop lets me also put DIMM2, so I'm a little confused.

Is SODIMM also dual channel, or is it a single or two memory stick ? I guess it's worth the 16 euros to have dual channel... Is there a significant potential performance improvement here ?

What do you think ?

Comment: My Frech is not that good, but this seems to be an order configuration as used by Dell and similar shops. And DIMM2 probaly refers to the second SODIMM slot in the laptop. (Not to a type, to dual channel or not).

Comment: From the pricing, it sounds like they're using 2 dimms for those memory configuration. Why not email call, IM or otherwise contact the retailer and check?

Comment: I'll call monday, it's closed on saturday.

Comment: @Hennes I added the same screenshot option with the US version of the site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am somewhat guessing here, but I think that this is what they mean:

[image]

The motherboard has two SoDIMM slots, allowing the use of 1 or 2 SoDIMMs. (A [SoDIMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SO-DIMM) is a smaller version of a regular DIMM. They are mostly used in laptops and small form factor computers).

1. 1x 4Gib SoDIMM. Cheapest.  One free socket to add more memory.
2. 2x 4GiB SoDIMMs. All sockets filled. Allows dual channel access which increases speed by about 5%.
3. 1x 8GiB with one SoDIMM. No dual channel, but you have room to add more memory later.
4. 12GiB in the form of one 4GiB SoDIMM and one 8GiB SoDIMM. Depending on the memory controller this does either not allow dual channel mode, or a smart memory controller may allow dual channel mode on using the first 4GiB of the 8GiB SoDIMM and use the remaining 4GiB in normal mode.
5. 2x8GiB SoDIMMs. Dual channel mode possible. No more room to add more memory later.

Note that all configurations use SoDIMMs.

Assumed is that `2 DIMM` means `2 SoDIMMs used`.